# How can i track console application status from web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, console-application

I have created one console application which is running some python script. output of console application is two file will create at destination and i am calling this console application from my web application. i am getting problem in tracking console application status from web.

Console Application Code:

```
Process process = new Process();
sortOutput = new StringBuilder("");
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\TensorFlow\tensorflow-for-poets-2";
process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(CaptureError);
process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(MyProcOutputHandler);
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("set IMAGE_SIZE=224");
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("set ARCHITECTURE=\"mobilenet_0.50_%IMAGE_SIZE%\"");
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"python -m scripts.retrain \ --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks \ --how_many_training_steps=500 \ --model_dir=tf_files/models/ \ --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/%ARCHITECTURE% \ --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \ --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \ --architecture=%ARCHITECTURE% \ --image_dir=tf_files/flower_photos");
process.StandardInput.Flush();
process.StandardInput.Dispose();
```

Web Application:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = 
Server.MapPath("~/Content/ConsoleApp1.exe");
process.Start();
Label1.Text = "done";
```

in background while console app in progress web app showing done..

Comment: You can try calling ``process.WaitForExit();`` after starting the process.

Comment: Is the console running on the web server, or on the client where the browser is? I don't believe the latter is possible.